# How do I add a pause between voice prompt choices in Twilio Voice using C#?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I'd like to be able to accomplish the following by editing the code below using Twilio Voice (TwiML) in C# (in a C#/Core Web Application):

- Add a brief pause of say 300ms between voice prompt choices
- Add emphasis to certain words in the prompt (e.g. friend, internet,
  other, etc)
- Allow user to say "friend" and interrupt the readout, which in turn invokes the action uri

Twilio has an example of how to mark up a "Say" object at https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech but it doesn't account for how to merge that with a gather object. It seems that merging the Say is the recipe so that the listener is able to interrupt the choices at any point by saying "friend", skipping the rest of the readout of choices, and to invoke the action Uri.

I have been able to construct a gather object and append separate Say methods as shown in my example code below. Note that the code below compiles and works, but I don't know how to pause the text-to-speech readout between options to give person a 300ms to blurt out "friend". Also, it seems to wait the entire three second default when you say "friend" instead of recognizing that as the user input and invoking the action uri more quickly. Using the keypad digits works as desired, but I want to get the speech-to-text capability to work more efficiently.

This is my first question posted, so let me know if I need to include any other information.

Here are my relevant "using" statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Twilio.AspNet.Common;
using Twilio.AspNet.Core;
using Twilio.TwiML;
using Twilio.TwiML.Voice;
```

Here is the function in the class I am working on:

```
private static void RenderReferralSource(VoiceResponse response)
{
  string hintchoices = "friend, internet, other,";
  List<Gather.InputEnum> bothDtmfAndSpeech =
   new List<Gather.InputEnum>(2) { Gather.InputEnum.Dtmf, Gather.InputEnum.Speech };
   var mygather = new Gather(input: bothDtmfAndSpeech,
     action: new Uri("/voice/GatherReferralSource", UriKind.Relative),
     speechModel: Gather.SpeechModelEnum.NumbersAndCommands,
     enhanced: true,
     hints: hintchoices,
     bargeIn: true,
     speechTimeout: "3",
     numDigits: 1);
   mygather.Say("How did you find us, or who referred you to our practice?", voice: "Polly.Joanna-Neural");
   string digmenu = "I will read a list of five choices. Press the number or say the word ";
   digmenu += "as soon as you hear the correct choice of who referred you, ";
   mygather.Say(digmenu);
   mygather.Say("Press 1, or say Friend, if a friend, family member, or other customer of ours referred you,");
   mygather.Say("Press 2, or say Internet, if you found us on Google or through an internet search,");
   mygather.Say("Press 3, or say Martian, if someone from Mars referred you,");
   mygather.Say("Press 4, or say Chuck Norris, if he ordered you to visit us,");
   mygather.Say("Press 5, or say Other, for any other way,");

   // Ask user and gather response
   response.Append(mygather);

   // If no choice, redirect
   response.Redirect(new Uri("/voice", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Seems that either timeout or speechTimeout should set the wait for response. Strangely, you set it as string as opposed to int. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather?code-sample=code-gather-speech-or-dtmf-with-nested-say-4&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x

Comment: You are correct. I think that may solve one of my issues. I will try it with speechtimeout set to auto and see what happens.

Comment: Jakub, thanks! Setting speechtimeout to "auto" worked. I tried to set it also to an integer instead of string, but C# would not compile it unless it was a string. Hence, setting it to "auto" as a string worked.

Comment: Got two of three issues solved. I can now pause by pre-pending the .pause(1) method before each .say("text to say") method, as in mygather.Pause(1).Say("text to say"); You can't pause any less than a second. I'd like to have more control in the millisecond range, as you do with the Break method you can use on the Say object that isn't suffixed on a gather. Last puzzle piece is how to put emphasis and some of the other fine tuning you can do with a Say object.

Comment: Use SSML, Text-to-Speech - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#ssml, that will allow you to control the TTS when using Polly voices.

Comment: Alan, thanks for trying to help. But, yes, I have been able to modify a say object just as the example at the link shows. What I cannot figure out is how to then attach that say object and merge it as part of the gather.

Comment: It would be helpful if someone could capture all these learnings from the comments in an actual answer.  This question deserves an answer and it is simply too hard to decode it from all the back and forth in the comments.